# When to use "no" and "not"

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

I am stuck with this sentence:

> There is no any reason to use it

In some contexts it's pretty clear which of the two words to use. But another, like the example above, is confusing me. So how would I say it: "**no** any reason" or "**not** any reason"?

Comment: You wouldn't normally use *any* in the first place. Just *"There's no reason to use it"*. If you want to be emphatic, more likely would be *"There is **absolutely** no reason to use it"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to say one of these two:

> There **is not (isn't)** any reason for you to do that.

or

> There is (There's) **no** reason for you to do that.

Many EFL students say "no any", but it's always incorrect in all dialects of English.