# 'no {noun}' vs 'not a {noun}'

Tags: difference, negation

What are the similarities and differences? When are they interchangeable and not?

I ask my question in general, but thought to offer an esoteric example, which I chose because [its difficulty enticed me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42834/8712). [Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=I2sRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%22no+reason%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-nH6VNXaCNetyATW0oL4DA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgo#v=onepage&q=no%20reason&f=false) p 249, *Critique of Pure Reason, Volume 2*, by Immanuel Kant.

> If we only mean 
>   objects of a non-sensuous intuition, to which our 
>   categories do not apply and of which we can have 
>   no knowledge whatever (either intuitional or conceptual), there is **no reason** why noumena, in this 
>   merely negative meaning, should not be admitted, 
>   because ...

Comment: Helpful reading - [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178911/the-difference-between-no-not-and-none), [2](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/when-to-use-no-and-not), [3](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/difference-between-no-and-not)

Comment: @Man_From_India Thank you for your links. Does [2](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3532/8712) truly answer my question? It only presents the two options as in my OP above; it doesn't discriminate between them?

Comment: Well the first link is the most informative, and the third one shows the differences. As for third link, I just added it if you need :-) you can skip it as well :-)

Comment: Just when you think you understand negation in English, [along comes](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/44224/6700) a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case of negating the statement **There is a reason for this**. One way to do it would be **There is *no reason* for this** - here, you're negating the noun. You could also say **There *isn't* a reason for this** - here, you're negating the verb. It's true that "isn't" expands to "is not", so you get "not a reason" in the middle, but it's important to understand that the "not" is attached to the verb ("is"), not to the noun ("a reason").

With that understanding, we can spot a broader pattern

- You are **no friend** of mine OR You **are not** a friend of mine.
- She was **no specialist** in that area OR She **was not** a specialist in that area.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**There was not an eye in the room that was dry after her heart-wrenching performance.

No eye in the room was dry after her heart-wrenching  performance.

There was not a dry eye in the room after her heart-wrenching performance.**

**There's not a country on the planet that will take him in.

No country on the planet will take him in.**

*At the logical level, they're indistinguishable.*  The difference is a matter of style and register. As such, the question touches upon literary interpretation, which is off-topic, and so I won't go there.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the two excellent answers already given, there is no difference in substantive meaning.

There may be a slight difference in emphasis.

> There isn’t a reason

strikes me as slightly more neutral then

> There is no reason

but that may just be a personal idiosyncrasy.

To know what Kant intended, you would need to look at the original German and ask someone knowledgeable about any difference in meaning between “kein” and “nicht.”